# Бот не отвечает в лс, aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Делаю бота, который отправляет сообщение, а потом его изменяет. Хочу, чтобы пользователь при нажатии на кнопку переходил в лс с самим ботом и пишет ему /start, а в ответ получает текст песни. Пытался сделать обработчик /start, брал пример из доки, но безуспешно. Примечательно, что сама функция даже не вызывается.

```
def get_music_info():
    client.init()
    queues = client.queues_list()
    last_queue = client.queue(queues[0].id)
    last_track_id = last_queue.get_current_track()
    last_track = last_track_id.fetch_track()

    artists = ', '.join(last_track.artists_name())
    title = last_track.title
    message = f"Слушает сейчас: {artists} - {title}."

    return message

def get_lyrics():
    client.init()
    queues = client.queues_list()
    last_queue = client.queue(queues[0].id)
    last_track_id = last_queue.get_current_track()
    last_track = last_track_id.fetch_track()
    artists = ', '.join(last_track.artists_name())
    title = last_track.title
    message = f'Сейчас играет {artists} - {title}'
    try: 
        lyrics = last_track.get_lyrics('TEXT')
        lyrics_1 = f'{message}\n{lyrics}\nИсточник: {lyrics.major.pretty_name}'
    except:
        lyrics_1 = 'Текст песни не найден.'
    return lyrics_1

USERS = []

async def send_message_every_minute():
    while True:
        message_text = get_music_info()
        inline_btn_1 = InlineKeyboardButton('Узнать текст песни', url=YOUR_URL)
        inline_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2).add(inline_btn_1)
        for user in USERS:
            chat_id = user['chat_username']
            message_id = user['message_id']
            current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            message_text_with_time = f"{message_text}\nВремя: {current_time}"
            await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=chat_id, message_id=message_id, text=message_text_with_time, reply_markup=inline_keyboard)
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    lyr = get_lyrics()
    await message.reply(lyr)
    
async def on_startup(dp):
    message = await bot.send_message(chat_id=YOUR_CHANNEL, text=YOUR_TEXT)
    USERS.append({'chat_username': YOUR_CHANNEL, 'message_id': message.message_id})
    await send_message_every_minute()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`await send_message_every_minute()` - это строка заставляет бота ждать пока выполнится `send_message_every_minute()`. Правильная реализация будет через `loop`:

```py
async def on_startup(dp):
    message = await bot.send_message(chat_id=YOUR_CHANNEL, text=YOUR_TEXT)
    USERS.append({'chat_username': YOUR_CHANNEL, 'message_id': message.message_id})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    loop.create_task(send_message_every_minute())

    executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=on_startup)
```